# How to call same code on pageshow and scroll top

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

I'm using jQuery Mobile, I have a bunch of javascript code that is executed like this

```
$(document).on("pageshow", function () {
  $(function () {
    var $container;
    $container = $(".items-section");
    return $container.imagesLoaded(function () {
      $container.masonry({
        itemSelector: "article.hlisting"
      });
      return $container.masonry({
        isFitWidth: true
      });
    });
  });
});
```

But since I'm retrieving objects via ajax and redrawing them on screen, some of the same code needs to be also executed inside of a  `$(document).on("scrollstop", function()`

My question is. How can I refactor the code in order to be called on two cases?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's exactly the same code that you want to be called then just pass multiple, space separated events as the first argument:

```
 $(document).on("pageshow scrollstop", function() {
     // your code here
 });
```